# How do you define different art board sizes for a custom Document Profile in Illustrator CS6 on Mac OSX?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do you define different artboard sizes for a custom Document Profile in Illustrator CS6 on Mac OSX?

The default profiles all have options for different sized artboards. It should be easy to set this up and I can't figure it out.

I know how to make new document profiles and put them where they belong. 
Home > Library > Application Support > Adobe > Adobe Illustrator CS6 > en_US > New Document Profiles

Comment: I think what I'm asking is, how do you setup custom Artboard Presets? It doesn't look like you can.

Answer (score 2):

If you select the `Browse` option when creating a new document, it will open a window showing the location of the Document profiles.

[image]

On the Mac it's in `users/[you]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator XX/en_us (or your language)/New Document Profiles`

If you create a document, set it up however you want in terms of color space, number of artboards, etc. and **save as to that same location** it will be seen in the drop down for `Profile:`. In the image below, I created the "3-Up" document and just saved it to the proper location.

[image]

The overall document structure is saved, including number of artboards, color space, DRES ppi, Preview mode - basically anything in the "New Document" windows will be retained by saving the file after it is created.

This procedure works fine in CS6 or newer. I can't say for certain if it works in previous versions. I do not have them loaded to test.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it's not possible to do this yet.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1354773